# selected date from calendar into text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to put the date selected from a Calendar into a text box.

I keep getting the error message that a date can't be converted to a string.

I am very new to coding and can't figure out how to parse it properly so that it would work.

Can anyone help me? I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what you have tried..

Comment: cdrDepart.SelectedDate = TxtTrvFrm.ToString();

Comment: Your question says, your trying to put a `the date selected from a Calendar to a text box` but you code shows the reverse.

Comment: Can you show us your Input in `TxtTrvFrm`. Need to check its format

Comment: TxtTrvFrm.ToString() = cdrDepart.SelectedDate;

Comment: That is a text box dropped in and the calendar is also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign a TextBox object with a String. 
You can only get or set its Text property `TxtTrvFrm.Text`

From your example

**Wrong:**

```
TxtTrvFrm.ToString() = cdrDepart.SelectedDate
```

**Correct:**

```
TxtTrvFrm.Text = cdrDepart.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

You could also use ToString or Text to get the current selected value of datePicker.

```
        //Output: 3/28/2013 12:00:00 AM
        TxtTrvFrm.Text = this.datePicker1.ToString();

        //Output: 3/28/2013
        TxtTrvFrm.Text = this.datePicker1.Text;

        //Output: 3/28/2013 12:00:00 AM
        TxtTrvFrm.Text = this.datePicker1.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

Comment: @user2217990: Does this answer your question?

Comment: This is what finally worked.... Thanks so much!!!   TxtTrvFrm.Text = cdrDepart.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

Answer (score 0):

You would normally just call ToString().  Can you show your code?

Comment: cdrDepart.SelectedDate = TxtTrvFrm.ToString();

Comment: cdrDepart.SelectedDate = TxtTrvFrm.ToString(); & cdrDepart = TxtTrvFrm.ToString();

Comment: If you are trying to take the date from a calendar and write it to the textbox, then your statements are going the wrong direction.

Comment: As stated above your code shows reverse of what your have said.  If this is the case you would do cdrDepart.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtTrvFrm.ToString())

Answer (score 0):

When I convert a selected date in a calendar to a string I use this:

```
string dateTime= Calendar.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one its a lambda version

```
cdrDepart.SelectedDatesChanged += (a, b) =>
{
   TxtTrvFrm.text = cdrDepart.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yy'.'MM'.'dd");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put them in a variable then try it like this:

> string date = Convert.ToString(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
>
> TBDate.Text = date;